# Wait Asynctasks to finish before proceeding to new activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I used Asynctasks to verify some inputs on EditTexts, the problem is, even the asynctasks are in doinbackground() part, when I press the button next, it will go to the next activity. My problem is I used asynctasks for verifications.

Here is my code for Next Button:

```
 @Override
public void onNextClicked(StepperLayout.OnNextClickedCallback callback) {
    getData();
    new VerifyAppNameTask().execute(sAppName);

    f2 = edtAppCategoryET(sAppCategory);
    f3 = edtAppPlatformET(sAppPlatform);
    f4 = edtAppDescriptionET(sAppDescription);
    f5 = edtAppVersionET(sAppVersion);

    if (!f1 && !f2 && !f3 && !f4 && !f5)
    {

        bundleData = new Bundle();
        bundleData.putString("appName", sAppName);
        bundleData.putString("appCategory", sAppCategory);
        bundleData.putString("appPlatform", sAppPlatform);
        bundleData.putString("appVersion", sAppVersion);
        bundleData.putString("appDescription", sAppDescription);


        callback.goToNextStep();
    }
    else
    {
        displaySnackBar("Cannot proceed. Please fix the errors.").show();
    }

}
```

And for the Asynctask:

```
  class VerifyAppNameTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // use doInBackground() to make network calls, the returned value is
    // sent to onPostExecute()
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... data) {

        if (data[0].replace(" ","").isEmpty())
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "1";
        }
        else if (data[0].length() > 25)
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "2";
        }
        else if (checkAppName(data[0]))
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "3";
        }
        else
        {
            f1 = false;
            return "4";
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tilAppName.setErrorEnabled(true);
        switch(result)
        {
            case "1":   {tilAppName.setError("You can't leave this empty.");break;}
            case "2":   {tilAppName.setError("Maximum of 25 characters.");break;}
            case "3":   {tilAppName.setError("App Name already used.");break;}
            case "4":   {tilAppName.setError(null);tilAppName.setErrorEnabled(false);break;}

        }

    }
}
```

What I need is when I click the next button, it should wait for all asynctasks to finish first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f2 = edtAppCategoryET(sAppCategory);
    f3 = edtAppPlatformET(sAppPlatform);
    f4 = edtAppDescriptionET(sAppDescription);
    f5 = edtAppVersionET(sAppVersion);

    if (!f1 && !f2 && !f3 && !f4 && !f5)
    {

        bundleData = new Bundle();
        bundleData.putString("appName", sAppName);
        bundleData.putString("appCategory", sAppCategory);
        bundleData.putString("appPlatform", sAppPlatform);
        bundleData.putString("appVersion", sAppVersion);
        bundleData.putString("appDescription", sAppDescription);


        callback.goToNextStep();
    }
    else
    {
        displaySnackBar("Cannot proceed. Please fix the errors.").show();
    }
```

add this code in `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute` so it can help. After AsyncTask completes its task then this code runs. Hope it helps

Comment: Great. What if I have more than Asynctask? Like in my Registration Page, I have more than 2 asynctasks, one for the student ID, email, and username. I need to create asynctasks so that I can add inputs to other fields while checking the 1st edittext, rather than waiting to get the result before proceeding to another field.

Comment: @PaulJohnPulumbarit you can do it in sequence. you can also call asynctak1 and in asynctask1 call asynctask2 in sequence and at last asynctask add the code which you want to implment to implement after asynctask

Comment: if this helps you then mark this as a correct answer so others getting help from this. Happy to help @PaulJohnPulumbarit :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
StepperLayout.OnNextClickedCallback mCallback;
```

---

```
    @Override
    public void onNextClicked(StepperLayout.OnNextClickedCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
        getData();
        new VerifyAppNameTask().execute(sAppName);
    }
```

---

```
private void yourMethod(){
    f2 = edtAppCategoryET(sAppCategory);
    f3 = edtAppPlatformET(sAppPlatform);
    f4 = edtAppDescriptionET(sAppDescription);
    f5 = edtAppVersionET(sAppVersion);

    if (!f1 && !f2 && !f3 && !f4 && !f5)
    {

        bundleData = new Bundle();
        bundleData.putString("appName", sAppName);
        bundleData.putString("appCategory", sAppCategory);
        bundleData.putString("appPlatform", sAppPlatform);
        bundleData.putString("appVersion", sAppVersion);
        bundleData.putString("appDescription", sAppDescription);


        mCallback.goToNextStep();
    }
    else
    {
        displaySnackBar("Cannot proceed. Please fix the errors.").show();
    }
}
```

---

```
class VerifyAppNameTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // use doInBackground() to make network calls, the returned value is
    // sent to onPostExecute()
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... data) {

        if (data[0].replace(" ","").isEmpty())
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "1";
        }
        else if (data[0].length() > 25)
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "2";
        }
        else if (checkAppName(data[0]))
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "3";
        }
        else
        {
            f1 = false;
            return "4";
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tilAppName.setErrorEnabled(true);
        switch(result)
        {
            case "1":   {tilAppName.setError("You can't leave this empty.");break;}
            case "2":   {tilAppName.setError("Maximum of 25 characters.");break;}
            case "3":   {tilAppName.setError("App Name already used.");break;}
            case "4":   {tilAppName.setError(null);tilAppName.setErrorEnabled(false);break;}
        }
        yourMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declared a boolean in your AsyncTask name 'isFinish'.
2. Set it true in onPostExecute()
3. Check isFinish before start next Activity

This is my sample

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (null != asyncTask && asyncTask.isFinished) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NextActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
```